# How to use QWidget with QItemDelegate and QTableView

Tags: python, qt, position, pyqt5, qitemdelegate

Doble-clicking the item in `QTableView` brings up the `QWidget` which is created by `QItemDelegate`s `createEditor()` method.
The problem is that the `QWidget` is offset from the QTableView window and it is floating somewhere on a desktop (at the corner of the my desktop). How to make sure the `QWidget` created by `createEditor` method is properly positioned?

[image]

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

app = QApplication([])


class PopupView(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PopupView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Popup)
        self.move(QCursor.pos())
        self.show()


class ItemDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        return PopupView(parent)


class Model(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self.items = [[1, 'one', 'ONE'], [2, 'two', 'TWO'], [3, 'three', 'THREE']]

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return 3

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return 3

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return

        if role in [Qt.DisplayRole, Qt.EditRole]:
            return self.items[index.row()][index.column()]


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()
        mainWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)
        mainWidget.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())

        view = QTableView()
        view.setModel(Model())
        view.setItemDelegate(ItemDelegate(view))
        self.layout().addWidget(view)


view = MainWindow()
view.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to re-implement the delegate's [updateEditorGeometry](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html#updateEditorGeometry) method, which will allow you to customise the geometry of the editor in whatever way you like. Your editor and delegate classes would then simplify to this:

```
class PopupView(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PopupView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Popup)

class ItemDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ItemDelegate, self).__init__(parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        return PopupView(parent)

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index):
        editor.move(QCursor.pos())
```